# How do I use the jquery child selector (>) with a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two tables of options with radio buttons. The first contains sauce flavors (marinara, bbq, etc.) The second contains sauce amounts (regular, extra, etc.) The sauce amounts have three choices - left, whole, and right.

[image]

The HTML is messy and generated by a CMS which I don't have access to change, so I'm stuck working with what I have.

When a user chooses a sauce other than Marinara, the sauce amount options other than Regular Whole should be hidden.

[image]

I have some (ugly) jquery written that hides the sauce amount options and then re-displays the regular sauce option, but it displays the entire row, including the left and right radio buttons. I need to hide the left and right radio buttons, but keep the center (whole) button displayed.

The code for the table is rather huge; I've got a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yweq5/2/) that contains a larger chunk than I'm posting here.

This is what the sauce flavors rows look like:

```
<tr class="pb-radio">
        <td class="pb-radio-label pb-highlight"><label>Marinara Sauce</label></td>
        <td class="pb-left">
            <div class="">
                <input type="radio" name="sauce_flavor.left" class="pb-radio-sauce pb-marinara-sauce">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="pb-whole">
            <div class="pb-highlight">
                <input type="radio" checked="" name="sauce_flavor.whole" class="pb-radio-sauce pb-marinara-sauce">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="pb-right">
            <div class="">
                <input type="radio" name="sauce_flavor.right" class="pb-radio-sauce pb-marinara-sauce">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pb-radio">
        <td class="pb-radio-label "><label>Garlic Parm Sauce*</label></td>
        <td class="pb-left">
            <div class=""> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="pb-whole">
            <div class="">
                <input type="radio" name="sauce_flavor.whole" class="pb-radio-sauce pb-sauce-no-size-allowed">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="pb-right">
            <div class=""></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.pb-sauce-no-size-allowed').live('change', function() {
    // need to hide all radio buttons plus parent labels, except for Regular Sauce
    $('.pb-radio-sauce-size').closest('tr').hide();
    var x =  $('td.pb-radio-label>label:contains("Regular Sauce")').closest('tr');
    x.show();
    console.log($(x > 'td.pb-left'));
    console.log($('x > td.pb-left'));
    console.log($(x) > 'td.pb-left');
});

$('.pb-marinara-sauce').live('change', function() {
    $('.pb-radio-sauce-size').closest('tr').show();
});
```

In the first function, `x` is correct, and `x.show()` works. But when I try to get the two `td` elements necessary, all the attempts return either an empty object or false.

How can I get the child elements of a variable? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
x.children('td.pb-left');
```

---

Commented by [jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752738/jasper)

```
x.find(" > td.pb-left")
```

Comment: @Jasper Add your comment to answer :)

Comment: there is no reason to use find() here, Jasper's comment was just to show how could it be done using '>' but just because OP asked for it

Comment: @A.Wolff It's another way to think about the same problem. That's usually a boon rather than a hindrance. In particular, it could show inexperienced jQuery users just what `.children()` is doing.

Comment: @Jasper regarding performance and readability, it is a hindrance ;) Thx btw, just learnt a new word

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, `$('td.pb-left', x);`

It's basically "find `td.pb-left` in the context of `x`

It will match all descendants of x, not just the immediate children like the `>` selector.

Comment: That is not the same as the child `>` selector, but `$('> td.pb-left', x);` may work. Not a good use imo.

Comment: True. It wouldn't be just immediate children, but for this application they should behave the same. Unless there are nested elements.

Comment: Good point, but still would be nicer to use `x.find()` instead of putting jQuery variable as the second argument to jQuery function.